# how to use highcharts on ABP.NET angularjs

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to search for use examples,
Get the following result。
[use examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBDKe.png)

But I use ON ABP.net ,Display error [My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUOmo.png)

Will you have any solution? Thank you.

In addition: Please do not joke my English, these are from Google translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the highcharts files to .angular-cli.json

Also add it to module (eg: app.module.ts)